# SimpleFilterPart: today's date minus 180 Days

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud, soap, filters

I have to create `DataFilters` using SOAP API, therefore I have to define `FilterPart` using Java code. I can create this properly using UI and define filter as:

```
profile attributes match "Last Purchase Date" == today's date minus 180 Days
```

However, I have no idea how to map `today's date minus 180 Days` to Java code.

```
SimpleFilterPart filter = jax.createSimpleFilterPart();
filter.setProperty("Last Purchase Date");
filter.setSimpleOperator(SimpleOperators.EQUALS);
filter.getValue().add("today's date minus 180 Days");
return filter;
```

I can't find anything useful in documentation regarding my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is support for Data Filters in the ExactTarget SOAP API, it does not support all of the same options that are available in the UI.  Relative dates is one of those features that is not supported in the API.

Comment: That's really bad news for my client. However, thanks for sharing that information.

Comment: This is a bummer. I can confirm I just tried this as well using Today -7 Day and it truncates the -7 Day only giving me Today

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, you could do something like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// Subtract 180 days from the calendar
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -180);
SimpleFilterPart filter = jax.createSimpleFilterPart();
filter.setProperty("Last Purchase Date");
filter.setSimpleOperator(SimpleOperators.EQUALS);
filter.getValue().add(cal.getTime());
return filter;
```

You didn't say what format the filter value needed to be, look at the [Java Calendar methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for more format and output options

Comment: Thanks for hint. However, I can't use your example. This filter should be evaluated during execution. I can't hardcode date stamp in filter. This filter will be used to create FilterDefinition and will be reused every day.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, it seems your question changed (from java filter to "Datafilter" and didn't say it was related to ExactTarget.  Best of luck!

Comment: Yes, I added more details. No worries and thanks for help.