# SimpleFilterPart on date fields (EventDate)

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap, java, filters

I'm currently using the Java bindings of the Partner API to extract unsubs, clicks, bounces and other events. This is working as expected, however I'd like to slice my requests by a date range (similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27181/simplefilterpart-todays-date-minus-180-days)).

I'm trying to replicate the following logic (Ignore the fact that I've used SQL as pseudo-code) in my request such that I'm able to dynamically slice my requests using two input parameters (xxx, yyy):
`Select * from Unsubs Where EventDate > xxx and EventDate < yyy`

I'm currently using two SimpleFilterPart's combined in a ComplexFilter part to achieve this filtering logic. As below:

```
// Init Request data
RetrieveRequestMsgDocument retrieveRequestMsgDocument = RetrieveRequestMsgDocument.Factory
    .newInstance();
RetrieveRequest rreq = RetrieveRequest.Factory.newInstance();

// Other stuff removed from this extract ....

// Setup filter 1
SimpleFilterPart filter1 = SimpleFilterPart.Factory.newInstance();
filter1.setProperty("EventDate");
filter1.setSimpleOperator(SimpleOperators.GREATER_THAN);
filter1.setDateValue1Array(new GregorianCalendar[] { (GregorianCalendar) startDate });

// Setup filter 2
SimpleFilterPart filter2 = SimpleFilterPart.Factory.newInstance();
filter2.setProperty("EventDate");
filter2.setSimpleOperator(SimpleOperators.LESS_THAN);
filter2.setDateValue1Array(new GregorianCalendar[] { (GregorianCalendar) endDate });

// Combine filters
ComplexFilterPart cfp1 = ComplexFilterPart.Factory.newInstance();
cfp1.setLeftOperand(filter1);
cfp1.setLogicalOperator(LogicalOperators.AND);
cfp1.setRightOperand(filter2);
rreq.setFilter(cfp1);

RetrieveRequestMsgDocument.RetrieveRequestMsg retrieveRequestMsg = retrieveRequestMsgDocument
    .addNewRetrieveRequestMsg();
retrieveRequestMsg.setRetrieveRequest(rreq);
```

Ultimately the Java builds the following SOAP extract:

```
 <xml-fragment xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <par:ClientIDs>
    Stuff omitted
  </par:ClientIDs>
  <par:ObjectType>UnsubEvent</par:ObjectType>
  <par:Properties>Client.ID</par:Properties>
  <par:Properties>SendID</par:Properties>
  <par:Properties>SubscriberKey</par:Properties>
  <par:Properties>List.ID</par:Properties>
  <par:Properties>EventDate</par:Properties>
  <par:Properties>EventType</par:Properties>
  <par:Properties>BatchID</par:Properties>
  <par:Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</par:Properties>
  <par:Filter xsi:type="par:ComplexFilterPart">
    <par:LeftOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
      <par:Property>EventDate</par:Property>
      <par:SimpleOperator>greaterThan</par:SimpleOperator>
      <par:DateValue>2015-01-07T00:00:00.749Z</par:DateValue>
    </par:LeftOperand>
    <par:LogicalOperator>AND</par:LogicalOperator>
    <par:RightOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
      <par:Property>EventDate</par:Property>
      <par:SimpleOperator>lessThan</par:SimpleOperator>
      <par:DateValue>2015-01-08T00:00:00.749Z</par:DateValue>
    </par:RightOperand>
  </par:Filter>
</xml-fragment>
```

In the above example I’m attempting to extract Unsubs between 07/01/2015 and 08/01/2015 (UK date format).

**My question - is this the correct way to filter requests by date?** I'm seeing data from 06/01 and 07/01 returned from this request which implies my lower bound isn't working correctly. Am I fundimentally builing my requests incorrectly or is there some date normalization  need to perform?

Comment: Are you doing some sort of timezone conversion after the results are returned? ET web services always works on ET server time (-6 GMT CST, no daylight savings observed)

Comment: Nope, I'm creating a SimpleDateFormat and just dumping the string to the console for debugging. I thought ET WS were based on UTC?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of date formats I've used with success in filtering by date:

```
<RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
    <Property>InsertDate</Property>
    <SimpleOperator>lessThan</SimpleOperator>
    <DateValue>2015-01-23T00:00:00-06:00</DateValue>
</RightOperand>

<RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
    <Property>InsertDate</Property>
    <SimpleOperator>lessThan</SimpleOperator>
    <DateValue>2015-01-23T10:12:21</DateValue>
</RightOperand>
```